# Access BootstrapVue internal Data

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-vue

I am using the [b-table](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) of BootstrapVue. I bound a function to the @sort-changed, which is called, when an onclick event on a header is invoked. Now I implemented a column resize function to change the width of a column (events for mouseup, mousedown, mousemove). The problem is, that if the resize is done (= mouseup), the click event on the column is also fired and the sort-changed event is invoked. In the function, which is bound to this event I can just return, if I was resizing, but still internally the sort order of this column was changed (ascending, descending) and the sort icon on that column changed. Stop(Immediate)Propagation did not work. So how else can I prevent this?

I thought that I could simply change the sortDesc bool on that Column, but I don't know how to access the internal bootstrapvue data and if this is even possible.

If you have other/better solutions, please let me know! Thanks in advance!